# Problem with listing FTP file names on M66 OpenCPU with AT+QFTPNLST

Tags: ftp, opencpu, quectel

I have a hardware with quectel M66 module. I am also using the module as main processing unit, so the default Opencpu is quite changed. Also there is a watchdog applied to the module.

I am trying to open an FTP connection and get the file list on FTP with AT+QFTPNLST

opened connection with

AT+QIFGCNT=0

AT+QFTPUSER="---"

AT+QFTPPASS="---"

AT+QFTPOPEN="---",---

AT+QFTPPATH="/"

AT+QFTPCFG=4,"/COM/"

AT+QFTPNLST

FTP connection opens without problems (`AT+QFTPSTAT` returns `OPENED`). I can read, get, put etc. on FTP. 
`AT+QFTPNLST` returns `OK`, `CONNECT`, and `+QFTPNLST:1` but *not* the file name list. then the device goes to restart (because of the watchdog).

Any ideas why that happens?

thanks.